# How to show specific number of textboxes depending on user's choice?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

User can choose from 1-8 players and at the next page i want him to put names for each one. How i can make textboxes depending on their choice.
For example they pick 4, i want to show four textboxes so they can put four names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You past the variable (number of players) to the next page.  After getting the variable only add that many items into your collection.  Then display your collection.

**Page1.xaml.cs**

```
// then you navigate like this (From Page1)
int number_of_players = 4;
Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page2), number_of_players);
```

**Page2.xaml.cs**

```
int number_of_players = 0;

// and in target Page you retrive the information:
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    // get the number of players passed
    number_of_players = e.Parameter as int;   
}    


// add in the correct number of players into the observable collection
private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ObservableCollection<sample_model> my_list = new ObservableCollection<sample_model>();
    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_players; i++)
    {
        // where sample_model is a model of a player
        my_list.Add(new sample_model("player name"));
    }

    this.myListView.ItemsSource = my_list;
}
```

---

```XAML
<ListView x:Name="myListView">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Red">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding PlayerName}" Width="200" Height="200"></TextBlock>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```